# SharePoint 2016: user profile news channel problem

Tags: web-part, permissions, error, import, service

Good day,

I have such problem. I opened My profile and found the Web Part Errors on my "News Channel" page.

All Web Parts show error:

"The web part or web form control located on this page cannot be displayed or imported. You do not have permissions to add and customize the pages required to complete this action. Correlation id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXX"

I filtered Log file in UIsViewer by Correlation id, like in this article https://mariagraziamerlo.com/2016/05/31/4-steps-to-get-the-real-error-message-from-sharepoint-2013-log-files/

And found this error

"Error importing WebPart. Assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, TypeName. Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.MicroFeedWebPart.The web part or web form control located on this page cannot be displayed or imported. You do not have permissions to add and customize the pages required to complete this action."

I can't understand, what is wrong.

Before I tried to restrict personal site creating for all users. I opened Central Administration, clicked on “Manage service applications” -> “Manage User Permissions”. 
And I unchecked "Create personal site" and "Use Social Features" for NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users and All Authenticated Users, then I restarted User Profile Service. 
When I found the problems on "News Channel", I canceled this actions and  restarted User Profile Service again.
It didn't help.

I tried to delete users personal sites by PowerShell

$url = "http://MY SITE/my/"
$contextWeb = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://MY SITE/my/");

$ServerContext = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($contextWeb);

$UserProfileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServerContext);

$Profiles = $UserProfileManager.GetEnumerator();

foreach ($oUser in $Profiles ) {
        $UserProfileManager.RemoveUserProfile($oUser.item("AccountName"));
        write-host "This account ", $oUser.DisplayName, " was deleted" 
        Write-Host $oUser.item("AccountName");
}

The users profiles were deleted, then automatycally restored. But the "News Channel" errors didn't disappear...
I can't understand, how to fix this problem.

I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue before and successfully solved it.

Please check if you have "**Add and Customize Pages**” permissions on Site level.

If you are unable to locate this permission , you can create it by following below mentioned steps :-

1. Add a new permission level which only includes “Add and Customize
   Pages” permission, and then create a new SharePoint group with this
   permission level.
2. Add the users into the SharePoint group and then the users will get the
   “Add and Customize Pages” permission from the site level (site
   permission).

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply, 

but I have "Add and Customize Pages” permissions on http://MY_SITE collection level. How can I check my permissions on http://MY_SITE/my/ ?

Comment: Didnt get your question there mate !!!.

Comment: I am Site Collection Owner!

Comment: Okay, i understand the issue . Do you have access to Crawls on the Central Administration . I want you to locate the content source hosting the my sites and run a full crawl . Can you do this ?

Comment: Full crawl didn't help (

Comment: Oops !! This is getting interesting now . Are you getting a correlation ID or something .

Comment: I have created my personal site (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/configure-my-sites). And now I haven't Web part errors on News Channel page. I see Web parts "Sites", "People", "My subscriptions" and this message "Sorry, we were unable to display all the news feed alerts. While we are trying to fix this, review the list of sites, as well as people and their recent activities". What the reason of this message?